# Angular multiple inputs from array of objects

Tags: angular

I need to display multiple input field from an array of objects (testtttt in this example). I need to the `Action ({{i +1}})` to get the color red, if the input field is not filled in. How can i get test valid state from my input?

I know it is possible to ask the valid state of the name of the input `(action.valid)`. But in this case, the name has the number i in its name.

```
<div *ngFor="let test of testtttt; let i = index" layout="column" layout-wrap>
    <div>
      <div>
          <span>Action ({{i + 1}}):</span>
              <div>
                <mat-label>
                    <mat-form-field>
                      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="componentTest[i].description" required name="action + {{i}}">
                    </mat-form-field>
                </mat-label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

I tried this, but its giving errors.

```
<span [ngClass]="{'red': !(action + i).valid}">Action ({{i + 1}}):</span>
```

Comment: I'd recommend to read this article for example:
https://alligator.io/angular/reactive-forms-formarray-dynamic-fields/

Answer (score 0):

Add a template reference variable to your input and use it specify the element.

This is what mine looks like:

```
            <div class="form-group"
                [ngClass]="{'has-error': (firstNameVar.touched || firstNameVar.dirty) && !firstNameVar.valid }">
                <label class="col-md-2 control-label" 
                       for="firstNameId">First Name</label>

                <div class="col-md-8">
                    <input class="form-control" 
                           id="firstNameId" 
                           type="text" 
                           placeholder="First Name (required)" 
                           required 
                           minlength="3"
                           [(ngModel)]=customer.firstName
                           name="firstName"
                           #firstNameVar="ngModel" />
                    <span class="help-block" *ngIf="(firstNameVar.touched || firstNameVar.dirty) && firstNameVar.errors">
                        <span *ngIf="firstNameVar.errors.required">
                            Please enter your first name.
                        </span>
                        <span *ngIf="firstNameVar.errors.minlength">
                            The first name must be longer than 3 characters.
                        </span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Notice the template reference variable: `#firstNameVar`.

(This example does not use an index, but the index should not be needed as part of the template reference variable.)